# JSONAPI relationship names and foreign-key column names in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api, jsonapi-resources

I got started following https://github.com/cerebris/peeps for writing a backend for an ember app. My trouble kind of starts that I want to use `owner_id` as a foreign-key column to the `User` table and in the resource, I want the relationship to be called `owner` referring to `users`.

```rb
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rentals, foreign_key: :owner_id
end
#app/models/rental.rb
class Rental < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :owner_id
end
# app/resources/api/user_resource.rb
class API::UserResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  attributes :user_name, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :is_staff, :is_active, :is_superuser, :last_login, :date_joined
  has_many :rentals
end
# app/resources/api/rental_resource.rb
class API::RentalResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  attributes :title, :description, :city, :category, :image, :bedrooms

  has_one :owner
  filter :user
end
```

I am wondering which parameters I need to add to `has_one :owner` in order to signify that this should link to user resources?

Comment: Why not just change the association to `belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think [class_name](https://jsonapi-resources.com/v0.10/guide/resources.html#Options) should be enough

```
class API::RentalResource < JSONAPI::Resource
   has_one :owner, class_name: 'User'
```

Comment: With that I get `Internal Server Error: Can't join 'Rental' to association named 'owner'; perhaps you misspelled it?`